# Yii2: How to filter by 'date' and by 'time' from a 'datetime' db column

Tags: mysql, sql, gridview, filter, yii2

In a user table I have a `created_at` column. In a User AR model that becomes a property, and in `\yii\grid\GridView` I split that property onto `'columns' => ['created_at:date', 'created_at:time'],`

**Question:** How do I habilitate a search field for those respective given columns, I mean they aren't actual db columns, therefore not model properties. so I can't do

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'crated_at_date' => $this->crated_at_date,
            'created_at_time' => $this->created_at_time,
        ]);
```

I know the search field is related to `\yii\grid\Column::filterOptions` but more specifically I don't know how to specify the `andFilterWhere()` clause within the search model.

Comment: What is your date and time formats?

Comment: @InsaneSkull default ones. I'm not sure how is this relevant.

Comment: show `created_at` column value.

Answer (score 2):

In `searchModel()` you can try this way:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'like', 
    'FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")', 
    $this->crated_at_date
])
->andFilterWhere([
    'like', 
    'FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, "%h:%i:%s %p")', 
    $this->created_at_time
])
```

Well, It's not tested but I guess it will do the trick.

[FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Thanks man, I already figured this out, I'm using `->andFilterWhere(['like', 'TIME(created_at)', $this->createdAtTime]); `. There's another issue though. While it works. I have a timezone set in `Yii::$app->timezone` and the user inputs are expected in local timezone, on the other hand the db colum is in UTC. I'm triying this `->andFilterWhere(['like', "DATE(CONVERT_TZ('created_at', 'UTC', 'America/Tijuana'))", $this->createdAtDate])` is not working for some reason, but am I in the correct path? @InsaneSkull

Comment: @user1236524. You want to convert `America/Tijuana` to `UTC` right? and What is your `created_at`?

Comment: user input is treated like America/Tijuana, the db is in UTC. The where clause should compare from America/Tijuana to America/Tijuana (that is to say covert UTC to America/Tijuana by means of convert_tz). @insaneskull

Comment: `2016-06-03 02:30:16` Is not unix, it's just a timestamp as UTC everywhere in the application, just presented/formatted as America/Tijuana to the user. That's why the user input is expected to be America/Tijuana. @insaneskull.

Comment: @user1236524. You can try this way: `DATE(CONVERT_TZ('created_at', '-07:00', 'America/Tijuana'))`

Comment: use date range widget of Kartik -v

Answer (score 0):

You can filter more or less just by converting input datatime to time:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    '>=', 
    'crated_at_date_time', 
    strtotime($this->crated_at_date)
])
```